# Parse anchor tags which have img tag as child element

Tags: php, domxpath, domparser

I need to find all anchor tags, which have an `img` tag as child element. Consider the following cases,

```
<a href="test1.php">
 <img src="test1.jpg" alt="Test 1" />
</a>

<a href="test2.php">
 <span>
  <img src="test2.jpg" alt="Test 2" />
 </span>
</a>
```

My requirement is to generate a list of `href` attributes along with `src` and `alt`
ie,

```
$output = array(
 array(
  'href' => 'test1.php',
  'src'  => 'test1.jpg',
  'alt'  => 'Test 1'
 ),
 array(
  'href' => 'test2.php',
  'src'  => 'test2.jpg',
  'alt'  => 'Test 2'
 )
);
```

How can I match the above cases in PHP? (Using Dom Xpath or any other dom parser)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `$doc` is a `DOMDocument` representing your HTML document:

```
$output = array();
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
# find each img inside a link
foreach ($xpath->query('//a[@href]//img') as $img) {

    # find the link by going up til an <a> is found
    # since we only found <img>s inside an <a>, this should always succeed
    for ($link = $img; $link->tagName !== 'a'; $link = $link->parentNode);

    $output[] = array(
        'href' => $link->getAttribute('href'),
        'src'  => $img->getAttribute('src'),
        'alt'  => $img->getAttribute('alt'),
    );
}
```

Comment: @NikhilMohan: Sorry, changed a bit.  You have to actually query a `DOMXPath` attached to the document, not the document itself.

Comment: It's OK. I have fixed it with your first post :)
One more thing, how to find anchor tags which have no img tag as child element (Instead of `src` and `alt`, I need anchor text)?

Comment: First guess: query `//a[not(//img)]` to get non-image links, and query `//text()` from there to get each text node within those links.  You should probably collect their `nodeValue`s into an array and implode them to get the whole text value.

Comment: Just tried it...you'll want to query `//a[not(.//img)]` for the links.  The dot is apparently significant; without it, seems the expression means "any `<a>` tags, but only if there are no images from the context node down" -- and the context node defaults to the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

Use Simple HTML DOM Parser http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You can do something like this (Rough Code, you will have to tune the code  to get it to work. ):

```
 //include simple html dom parser
 $html = file_get_html('your html file here');

foreach($html->find('a') as $data){
   $output[]['href']=$data->href;
   $output[]['src']=$data->src;
   $output[]['alt']=$data->alt;

}
```

Comment: The `src` and `alt` attributes are on the image inside the link.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your HTML is a valid XML document (has a single root node, etc), you can use SimpleXML like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);
$items = array();
foreach ($xml->xpath('//a[@href]') as $anchor) {
    foreach ($anchor->xpath('.//img[@src][@alt]') as $img) {
        $items[] = array(
            'href' => (string) $anchor['href'],
            'src' => (string) $img['src'],
            'alt' => (string) $img['alt'],
        );
    }
}
print_r($items);
```

This uses xpath to search through the document for all `<a>` tags that have an `href` attribute. Then it searches under each `<a>` tag found to find any `<img>` tags that have both `src` and `alt` tags. It then just grabs the needed attributes and adds them to the array.